# unable to rotate the ubuntu screen without using xrandr?

Tags: screen, rotate

Recently, I've encountered an issue where the display automatically rotates, causing inconvenience and disruption to my workflow. After troubleshooting, I've determined that this rotation feature is not desirable for my setup.

Would it be possible to disable the screen rotation on my Ubuntu system? I understand that this may require adjustments to the system configuration or settings. I would greatly appreciate any assistance or guidance you could provide in resolving this matter.